# regexp_count is returning incorrect count(Redshift)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am executing the following query on redshift:

```
select regexp_count('N|M|C|K|','|')
```

Result:9

Expected Result: 4

As per my understanding, the regexp_count returns an integer that indicates the number of times the pattern occurs in the string. According to my understanding, it should return 9. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: You need to escape pipe `regexp_count('N|M|C|K|', '\|')`

Comment: Same result is returned when i execute regexp_count('N|M|C|K|', '\|') i.e 9

Comment: Try also: `regexp_count('N|M|C|K|', '\\|')` and `regexp_count('N|M|C|K|', '[|]')`

Comment: They both return 4(expected result). Any idea why select regexp_count('N|M|C|K|','|') doesn't return 4.

Comment: Pipe `|` is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped if you intend for it to be _literal_.